# Convert file located in OSGi Bundle to IFile

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, osgi

I have an installed bundle (org.osgi.framework.Bundle) in my running eclipse. There is a file in this bundle. I have the path to the file and i can represent this file by an URL (java.net.URL) by using `URL url = bundle.getEntry("/folder/file")`.

Is there a way to get a handle of this file of type IFile (org.eclipse.core.resources.IFile)?

I need a reference of the file located in the installed osgi bundle of type IFile. But I **don't** want to copy the file temporary on my local disk (like workspace).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's difficult. An `IFile` represents an actual file rather than an entry in an archive. You would need to build an Eclipse FileSystem (EFS) representation for the archive, but that's likely to be a lot of work.

What are you trying to achieve? There's probably something you can do that is much simpler.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. To be more detailed: The user of the tool I write has the possibility to open special files in an editor. Those files can be located either in their workspace or they are provided by bundles they start with their IDE (new Feature). But the old implementation expects an IFile to show within the editor. I don't know how to open files provided by the started bundle within the editor. The worst case for me is to rewrite the editor to expect not the IFile but something else (like a new model or so). But I hoped I don't need to rewrite so much ;)

Comment: Thanks for the details. The editor probably assumes an `IFileEditorInput` as its input object... this is bad practice but I guess that doesn't help you much. You could try and see whether it will accept an `IStorageEditorInput`, which is much easier to implement for non-file inputs.

Comment: That's it, you brought me on the right path. The editor actually assumes an IEditorInput which I was able to implement on my own. Now it works fine. Thank you!

Comment: Why is it bad practice by the way?

Answer (score 2):

If you have an eclipse plugin / editor or something like this try:

```
//get the workspace
IWorkspace workspace= ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace();

//create the path to the file
IPath location= new Path(yourURL.getPath());

//try to get the IFile (returns null if it could not be found in the workspace)
IFile file= workspace.getRoot().getFileForLocation(location);

if (file == null) {
    //not found in the workspace, get the IFileStore (external files)
    IFileStore fileStore = EFS.getLocalFileSystem().getStore(location);
    return fileStore;
} else {
    // file found, return it
    return file;
}
```

Helpfull could be also:

```
url = FileLocator.toFileURL(yourURL);
```

and/or

```
URL resolvedUrl = FileLocator.resolve(url);
```

After this you can create the input for your editor (I think you want to use it there?)

```
Object file = myGetFile();
IEditorInput input;
if (file instanceof IFile) {
    input = new FileEditorInput((IFile)file);
else {
    if (file instanceof IFileStore) {
        input = new FileStoreEditorInput((IFileStore)file);
    } else {
       throw new MyException("file is null, not found");
    }
}
```

I hope this will help you.

Greetz,
Adreamus

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But `workspace.getRoot().getFileForLocation(location);` only finds files within the workspace. Even FileLocator or other classes that can access files on the file system do not work since i need an interface to the OSGi framework.

Comment: Hi, I included the workspace only for the creation of IFile, they are loaded in the workspace. All external files are loaded with the EFS.getLocalFileSystem().getStore(IPath). It works for files in bundles too! (take a look at http://lotuseclipsecorner.blogspot.com/2009/03/getting-access-to-files-in-eclipse-rcp.html). But there exists more then 1 possibility, and you chose another one like I can see in the other comment ;-)